# Way to verify/compute some zeros of the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, computational-mathematics

Consider a complex function, possibly the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(1/2+it).$ $W_t(x)=\zeta(1/2+it)^{\big(\frac{1}{\log(x)}+\frac{1}{\log(1-x)}\big)}.$ Here $t$ is a time parameter and cycles through values, say from $t\in(1,\infty).$ Letting $x\in(0,1)$ and starting the clock, is this a way to record some zeros of $\zeta(1/2+it)?$ When $\zeta(1/2+it)=0,$ this corresponds to $W_t(x)=0.$ I think $W_t(x)$ will blow up near $x=0,1$ when $\zeta(1/2+it)$ equals zero, and oscillate quietly when $W_t(x)$ is far from a zero. I know that this notion needs to be defined better, and I'm not sure how to do that. My thought was that maybe if you could run a program, the computer could easily pick up when $W_t(x)$ flares up and record the zero? Does this sound plausible?

Here is what a graph looks like for $W_{123}(x).$ So I think we are close to a zero. The closest zero is $122.946829294.$

[image]

And here is a graph of $W_{123.7}(x).$

[image]

Notice how we are relatively far from a zero. In fact we're about halfway between two zeros, $122.946829294$ and $124.256818554,$ so I think the oscillation should relax and the complex and real curves should have more space between them.

Comment: How do you compute $W_t$? Concretely I mean.

Comment: From my understanding, please correct me if I'm wrong, but I would say at $t=123$ you would write $W_{123}(x)=\zeta(1/2+123i)^A.$ $A$ is the entire exponent.

Comment: How exactly do you compute the zeta though? Usually one looks at the Hardy functions and uses Riemann Siegel to find tons of sign changes, so zeroes - my question is how would you do better (concretely)?

Comment: @Conrad sorry, I'm working on it. I'm trying to come up with a way to measure the level of oscillation of the real and complex curves

Comment: I understand - but my point is that concretely how do you plan to compute the zeta in the critical strip? There are approximations to it, sure (best being Riemann Siegel on the crtical line but there are others too), but how do you do it concretely? What formula would you use in other words, if you want to quantify it in a program?